# Increase left margin of odd pages only using the booklet package

Tags: margins, booklet

I'm using the booklet package with the default options like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[print]{booklet}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

which works fine, except that the layout is not quite balanced, in that the left margin for the odd pages is much smaller than that of even pages when you fold the paper into the a5 booklet.  I looked through the documentation but didn't see an easy way to control the odd page margin (as these are "fake" pages, the usual commands for odd/even control do not work).

Comment: You could use post-processing tools like [pdfxup](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfxup), [pdfjam](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfjam), and [pdfbook2](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfbook2) instead, maybe retaining more control that way

Comment: You are using the wrong paper size. The default for `article` is `letterpaper`. So the default of source width and source height and target width and target height are also for letter paper. You should at least use `article`'s option `a4paper` to make an a5 booklet. IMHO using `a5paper` and explicitly set the target size using `\target` would be better. And maybe option `twoside` could also be a good idea.

Comment: @cabohah Great Thanks!  I'm so stupid, it hasn't occurred to me to think of the paper size, I completely forgot wasn't a4, I was completely focused on the margins (doh!) If you cut/paste as answer I can accept it, it worked a charm - THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong paper size. The default for `article` is `letterpaper`. So the default of source width and source height and target width and target height are also for letter paper. You should at least use article's option `a4paper` to make an a5 booklet.

There are more alternatives, e.g., using option `a5paper` and explicitly setting source and target size using `\source` and `\target`. Also option `twoside` could be useful for booklets.

And indeed there are several alternatives to generate a booklet from a PDF, e.g. using:

```
pdfjam --landscape --suffix booklet --a4paper --signature 8 -- input.pdf
```

for a booklet with 8 pages (from a PDF with 5–8 pages). Internally `pdfjam` uses [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) and it supports all options also available for that package. So you can use options like `--scale`, `--offset`, `--trim` and much more to arrange the pages of the source PDF to an output PDF.